# Compare dates per each month in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an issue while comparing dates. I want to compare my end_time column on my table with some average arithmetic value, for many rows.

```
    when  PPLP_NAME='OCS_PPL_IMP_OFFER_STATE' then
    CASE WHEN   ( to_char(END_TIME,  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')<= '011100' )
    THEN 100 ELSE 0 END
END
AS STATUS,
```

For example i want to compare the end_time for the above PPLP_NAME to be lower or equal to 01 of each month at 11am.

Below query does not do the requested.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks a lto.

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag since `TO_CHAR` is an Oracle function. If this is incorrect then please edit in the correct tags (rather than tagging multiple RDBMS).

Comment: Correct, thanks MT0 7 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string comparisons to compare dates - just compare the dates:

> i want to compare the end_time for the above PPLP_NAME to be lower or equal to 01 of each month at 11am.

Then you need to see whether the date is less than or equal to the date `TRUNC`ated the start of the month with 11 hours added to it:

```
WHEN PPLP_NAME='OCS_PPL_IMP_OFFER_STATE' then
  CASE
    WHEN END_TIME <= TRUNC( END_TIME, 'MM' ) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR
    THEN 100
    ELSE 0
  END
END AS STATUS,
```